# Controlling reveal API in embedded slid.es presentation from parent page

Tags: iframe, same-origin-policy, reveal.js

I'm working on a way to trigger slide advancements in an embedded reveal.js-powered slid.es presentation. I have a parent page that embeds a local version of the slides via an iframe (on the same domain as the test page):

```
<iframe id="slidesdivlocal" src="slides-embed.html" width="576" height="420" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

In this setup I can successfully control the reveal API within the iframe by using things like:

```
document.getElementById("slidesdivlocal").contentWindow.Reveal.left();
```

I would like to be able to also control embedded presentations that are iframed from the external slid.es domain as this makes the embedding so much easier. When I try this I run into a security issue because the parent page and iframed embedded page do not have the same origin:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost" from accessing a frame with origin "http://slid.es". Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
```

[This is an example](http://fromtimetoti.me/lab/popcorn-slides-plugin/reveal-embed-test.html) that shows what happens to the two different embeds when triggered left() or right() via button clicks.

I see people suggesting [Cross-window messaging](http://javascript.info/tutorial/cross-window-messaging-with-postmessage) to work around this, but I only have control over the parent page, so this is not really an option.

Is there a way to embed slid.es presentations via an iframe to their external site and still control them via their Reveal API methods?

Answer (score 0):

I've had some chats about this and it turns out Im actually asking for the impossible here. Controlling a JS API running on another domain from a parent page through an iframe without having access to the other domain isnt something you can do, nor should want to do.

Ill be making the connection to locally hosted reveal.js slides rather to ones that are hosted on slid.es